# Datos separados por comas a nuevas celdas

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un fichero de excel con los datos de cada partido de la premier league y quiero hacer una analisis de goles para lo cuál necesito el valor en celdas diferentes y no por comas.

Sabeis alguna forma para hacer esto rápido?

Aquí tenéis un ejemplo:

[image: Datos premier legue]

Y yo quiero que me salgan los goles (away and home) por fila en vez de todos juntos separados por una coma.

Gracias!

Comment: Datos  --> Texto en columnas --> Delimitados --> y marcas coma como separador. No obstante esto te lo pega en las siguientes columnas a la celda, así que si las tienes ocupadas, te sobreescribirá los datos.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Para reorganizar tus datos, necesitarás una macro si los quieres ir pasando a filas, porque tienes que estar repitiendo datos. Tu pregunta ahora es demasiado amplia me temo.